# Face selection - but showing highlighted dots? (2.79)

Tags: selection-tools

I am not sure where it went wrong, I hope you can help, one of my mesh objects' face selection is different from the others, and I need it to stop it lol.

In face selection, it shows the faces as highlighted dots, instead of the whole highlighted face as per usual (which is so much easier to see and work with):
[image]

VS other objects in the same scene that work as normal:
[image: https://gyazo.com/5b59410211bc4fbd70ab9879d8d930f2]

The problematic object had a cloth modifier (made into a pillow), converted into mesh. It has no active modifiers, is converted to mesh, no vert groups, just like the other objects, if that makes a difference? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Deleting the faces shows no overlaps
[image]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Ahh thanks, I fixed the image links! And i am still on v2.79 :') (added vers in title too)

Comment: What if you delete one of those faces? is there a face below that?

Comment: Looks like doubled geometry to me as well.

Comment: Hey, i have just updated the question with a pic having deleted faces. Seems like not :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.79 the display options were stored separately for each object. That´s why the behavior can be different. Select the naughty object in editmode and tick the option `Faces` and/or `Edges` in Sidebar (N-Panel) > Mesh Display

[image]